# Problems with text that appears when hovering in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser

You know how when you hover over an image or a link, or even a form box, you'll get a little box of text that appears?  Well, I get an empty box.  Not sure what might be blocking that text from showing up, but it's really annoying.

I'm running Firefox 3.5.2 on Windows XP.

Could it be an ad-block issue? Or a java issue?  Any ideas on how to diagnose the issue? Or better yet, solve it?

Comment: What plugins and extensions do you have installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling all of your add-ons. If that doesn't work, reinstall FF.

Edit: Mark's comment pointed out this Google thread about the issue: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Toolbar/thread?tid=15f511df1aff2673

> Just a head's up in case you're seeing blank tooltips in Firefox 3.5 (now available!): please uninstall and reinstall the latest version of Toolbar from the Toolbar homepage:

http://www.google.com/toolbar

Comment: I did that.  It must be an add-on because now it's working.  I'm going to turn them back on one by one (what a pain!) and see if I can diagnose it.

Comment: I'll be damned it was Google Toolbar of all things.  How weird.  Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: No idea, but I'd suggest submitting a bug report. Also, try reinstalling the add-on first to make sure you don't just have a bad install.

Comment: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Toolbar/thread?tid=15f511df1aff2673

Comment: @mark Yep, thats it. Glad to see it's been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen with EVERY image? I'm pretty sure the text is what's written in the 'title' section of the  in the html. If they have nothing written, but specified it (like title="") it probably would show a blank box if you hover...?

Answer (score 0):

As a diagnostic warning, note that Internet Explorer (incorrectly) displays text in this box using "alt" attribute, whereas Firefox will use only the "title" attribute. If you're comparing the results of the two browsers this may be causing some confusion.